# Issue with Paypal Payment Acquirer in Odoo 12 CE return URL directing to loalhost. How to change it to my domain?

Tags: paypal, odoo-12

I'm using Odoo v12 CE.
I installed the accounting module which allows for payment acquirers to be set up. 
I set up my paypal account following the guidelines  from this link: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/12.0/ecommerce/shopper_experience/paypal.html

I already configured paypal and odoo and I can make payments when I send a quote to my customers. they get the link to the order in the customer portal and there, they can chose paypal as the payment method.

Then they are able to pay from paypal and it works. The issue is that after the payment, when they are redirected they are returned with the wrong URL.
The URL is :

http://localhost:8069/payment/paypal/dpn/?amt=1.16&cc=MXN&cm=%7B%22return_url%22%3A%20%22%2Fpayment%2Fprocess%22%7D&item_name=IDW%20Innovation%20Studio%3A%20SO118-1&item_number=SO118-1&st=Completed&tx=07600540TC4292804

If I change http://localhost:8069 to  https://example.com , then it actually works and the payment is received.

I don´t know what to do in order for it not to show localhost instead of mydomain.com. Is that a system parameter I have to create or something?